# Cannot draw image from WebApi call on Canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, canvas, asp.net-web-api

I have a working WebApi that delivers a PNG image to me (tested in Fiddler). However, when I want to draw the image an on HTML Canvas, nothing happens.

**Web api code**:

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetInitialMap(int height, int width)
{
    var chart = RmdbHelper.GetInitialChart(height, width);

    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    chart.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Png);

    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
    response.Content = new StreamContent(memoryStream);
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/png");
    response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;

    return response;

}
```

This is the **javascript and jquery code** to call the image and try drawing

```
var NavChart = function() {
    var ctx,
    chartHeight,
    chartWidth,

    // other stuff

    renderBackgroundMap = function() {
        $.get("../api/NauticalMaps/GetInitialMap?height" + chartHeight + "&width=" + chartWidth)
            .done(function (bgImage) {
                var background = new Image(chartWidth, chartHeight);
                background.src = bgImage;
                ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0);
            })
            .fail(function (error) {
                showError("...");
            });

    };

    initialize = function(canvasId) {
        var canvas = document.getElementById(canvasId);
        chartHeight = canvas.getAttribute("height");
        chartWidth = canvas.getAttribute("width");

        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        render();
    };

    return {
        initialize: initialize
    };
};
```

On the HTML page I create a NavChart object and call the initialize function. No problems until then. Fiddler shows me that the call is made and it returns a image.

**HTML and call**:

```
<div class="row">
    <canvas id="zeekaart" height="550" width="1150" style="border: 1px solid lightgrey"></canvas>
</div>


<script>
    var nav = new NavChart();
    nav.initialize("zeekaart");  
</script>
```

It seems that

```
var background = new Image(chartWidth, chartHeight);
background.src = bgImage;
```

the **.src** expects an URL or destination. But plainly using

```
.done(function (bgImage) {
    ctx.drawImage(bgImage, 0, 0);
})
```

doesn't work either.

Any ideas? I don't want to write all images away in a temp folder on the server and clear them after a specified time.

Comment: you have to wait that the img has loaded before drawing it to canvas.

Comment: How should I wait? I thought the image was "loaded" when you arive in the "done" function

Comment: no the promise is resolved, but to wait that the image has loaded you just have to use its onload handler.

Comment: How would you do that?

Comment: `background.onload=function(){ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0);} background.src = bgImage;`

Comment: Well, I tried several different combinations, it still doesn't work, eg:

            `$.get("../api/NauticalMaps/GetInitialMap?height=" + chartHeight + "&width=" + chartWidth)
                .done(function (bgImage) {
                    var background = new Image(chartWidth, chartHeight);
                    background.onload = function () {
                        ctx.drawImage(bgImage, 0, 0);
                    }
                    background.src = bgImage;
               })`

Comment: No, here you are setting the src in the onload, which will never occur obviously. Did you tried copy/pasting my comment above? Also there may be some other problems, I don't know about the wepapi call, but at least, you've got this one.

Comment: Ok, completely leaving out jquery like this works, but I'd prefer to keep .error part in for example (yes i copied it like you said):

`            var back = new Image();
            back.onload = function() {
                ctx.drawImage(back, 0, 0);
            }
            back.src = URLTOAPI;`

It's a workaround, but not what I expected :)

Comment: That's not a workaround, that is the way to do it. jquery is just an hellping library to do some DOM manipulations, here you're not doing any, so unrelevant. But if you really want to use it, then `$(back).on('load', function(){...});` would be the way to go, but seriously, that's silly.

Comment: You're right. I've been playing around with your code and it does the job. I'll update the post as fixed. Thx @Kaiido

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround presented by @Kaiido does the job well enough, like this:

```
var back = new Image();
back.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(back, 0, 0);
}
back.src = "../api/NauticalMaps/GetInitialMap?height=" + chartHeight + "&width=" + chartWidth;
```

***However***... I finally found the solution for my problem. Part of my problem was not returning a JSON object, by returning it as a plain image. When returning purely an image, the code above will do. But, by returning the image as part of a JSON object, you can directly use the image in the browser memory. Here's my solution:

A simple class for storing the data (which will be sent automatically as json) to the browser

```
public class NavigationMapData
{
    public byte[] MapData { get; set; }

    // ... other data goes in here as well     
}
```

The api-controller method:

```
public NavigationMapData Get(string id, double northing, double easting, double northing2, double easting2, int height, int width)
{
    NavigationMapData data = new NavigationMapData();
    // next method just returns a Bitmap object
    var img = RmdbHelper.GetChart(northing, easting, northing2, easting2, height, width);
    // convert the object
    data.MapData = img.ToByteArray(ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    return data;
}
```

For the completeness, the image extension for converting Image/Bitmap data into a byte[]:

```
public static class ImageExtensions
{
    public static byte[] ToByteArray(this Image image, ImageFormat format)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            image.Save(ms, format);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

The javascript/jquery code:

```
$.get(URL_TO_API_PLUS_PARAMS)
    .done(function (navMapData) {

        var img = document.createElement("img");
        // as seen on stackoverflow somewhere
        img.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + navMapData.MapData;
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    })
    .fail(function (error) {
        // onError actions
    })
    .always(function() {
        // onFinished actions
    });
```

Now I have more control over my api calls in case a bitmap or my data would not load.

Answer (score 0):

Your Web API is sending the raw image data, but "src" expects a URL.